# .parallactic_angle() method in PyEphem

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem

Changelog for Version 3.7.5.3 (2014 May 29) of PyEphem mentions that all bodies have been given a .parallactic_angle() method but I couldn't find it in [quick references](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html) or tutorial. What are the argument(s) it need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Compute parallactic angle using PyEphem.
city = ephem.city( ... )
moon = ephem.moon( city )
parallacticAngle = moon.parallactic_angle()
```

The code below is ripped from [indicator-lunar](https://askubuntu.com/a/292529/67335) and computes the parallactic angle, used to further calculate the bright limb angle.

```
# Compute the bright limb angle (relative to zenith) between the sun moon.
# Measured in degrees counter clockwise from a positive y axis.
# 'Astronomical Algorithms' Second Edition by Jean Meeus (chapters 14 and 48).
# 'Practical Astronomy with Your Calculator' by Peter Duffett-Smith (chapters 59 and 68).
city = ephem.city( ... )
moon = ephem.moon( city )
sun = ephem.Sun( city )

y = math.cos( sun.dec ) * math.sin( sun.ra - moon.ra )
x = math.cos( moon.dec ) * math.sin( sun.dec ) - math.sin( body.dec ) * math.cos( sun.dec ) * math.cos( sun.ra - moon.ra )
positionAngleOfBrightLimb = math.atan2( y, x )

hourAngle = city.sidereal_time() - moon.ra
y = math.sin( hourAngle )
x = math.tan( city.lat ) * math.cos( moon.dec ) - math.sin( moon.dec ) * math.cos( hourAngle )
parallacticAngle = math.atan2( y, x )
brightLimbAngle = math.degrees( ( positionAngleOfBrightLimb - parallacticAngle ) % ( 2.0 * math.pi ) )
```

Comparing my computed value to that of the PyEphem's, they both match (one is a float radians and the other prints as decimal degrees).

Comment: Thanks for the code @Bernmeister. But how do I use the the built in method to compute it?

Comment: @Nabigh The three line code example at the top of my answer should run as is, once you've added in your own city.